# PHP: Convert URL to regular expression to match specific domain

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to convert a URL to regular expression to match it with current URL. For example, I have a URL **http://www.example.com/example.php**
I want it to convert to 
**^(https?://)?(www\.)?example\.com\/example\.php/?(\?.*)?(#.*)?$**

So that I store it and whenever a user hits this url with any number of parameters attached to it, I will match that url with my regular expression and will perform some action based on the results.

I have found many questions but they all are either to match general URL (with any domain name) or with regular expressions given. But I want a function to which I will pass URL and it will return its regular expression and I will use it to match that specific domain.

Comment: Well take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @naruto I'm actually going to give that post a special place in my heart since it's sooo true! - Good read too btw ;)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand If only more people would do that, it would make lots of peoples day easier :P

Comment: You would probably be better off using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) and then comparing the components separately. One big regex to match an entire URL is going to cause problems.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused on the original question. You want to take a normal URL, convert it to a regular expression pattern, then use that pattern to match another URL?

Comment: Use the ``parse_url()`` method (as @Sverri M. Olsenuse mentioned) to get the url's contents, and then get the specific contents you want to build the regex.

Comment: @JakeB. exactly. Because the first URL is stored in a database, I fetch it, I want to convert it a regular expression and write it in a javascript file and give it to user to include in their own pages. but if I write simple url, it will not work if there is query string attached to the URL with which this URL will be matched.

Comment: You started out with a problem, trying to fix it with regex will cause you to have [2 problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I managed to fix it with regex and gladly it didn't create any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally created this code with the help of stackoverflow and other communities. This provides me the exact string I require against given URL.

```
<?php 
    function createrRegex($url) {
        $var1 = '^(https?://)?';
        $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        $host_parts = explode('.', $host);
        if (!empty($host_parts)) {
            $length = count($host_parts);
            foreach ($host_parts as $i => $part) {
                if ($i == 0) {
                    if ($part == "www") {
                        $var1 .= '(' . $part . '\\\\.)?';
                    } else {
                        $var1 .= '' . $part;
                        $var1 .= ($i < ($length - 1)) ? '\\\\.' : '';
                    }
                } else {
                    $var1 .= '' . $part;
                    $var1 .= ($i < ($length - 1)) ? '\\\\.' : '';
                }
            }
        }
        $path = '';
        if ((parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) != NULL)) {
            $path = str_replace('/', '\\\\/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
            $path = str_replace('.', '\\\\.', $path);
        }
        $var1 .= $path;
        $var1 .= '/?(\\\\?.*)?(#.*)?$';
        return $var1;
    }
?>
```